# How to optimize real-time database calls when getting 10 random users?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin-coroutines

I read this:

- [How to optimize Firebase Realtime Database calls to improve performance?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-optimize-firebase-realtime-database-calls-to-improve-performance-cc63dad374d5)

Where it is said that to optimize performance we have to duplicate data. So I created a section in the database called `users` to hold all user objects:

```
users
 \
  uid
   \
    -- name: "john"
   \
    -- email: "john@gmail.com"
   \
    -- age: 22
```

And a section to hold only the uid of the users:

```
uids
 \
  --- uid: true
 \
  --- uid: true
```

I have over 1250 users. What I need is to select 10 random users and display their data in the UI. I do that by reading the `uids` node, and I generate 10 random uids. Now for each one I create database request to read the details of the users. The problem is that each request takes ~ 1 second. To get 10 users, it takes 10 seconds. That's too much. How can I optimize this process?

---

Code:

```
while (userList.size < 10) {
    val randomId = Random.nextInt(userIdsList.size)
    val randomUser = usersRef.child(questionIdsList[randomId]).get().await().getValue(User::class.java)
    if (!userList.contains(randomUser)) {
        userList.add(randomUser)
    }
}
```

It looks to me that .await() gets the users one after another and not in parallel. Any ideas?

Comment: Tha last bit (loading 10 items taking 10x longer than loading a single item) does not align with my experience with the realtime database as Firebase can typically [pipeline the requests over its existing connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786). If you see something different than I explain there, can you edit your question to show the minimal code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi Frank. Thanks for commenting. I just added the code that behaves weird.

Comment: I'm not a Kotlin expert, but this is probably why the loads take more time `.await()`. Is there a way in Kotlin to fire off all `get()` calls at the same time, and then wait for all of them to complete?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just started to code in Kotlin. I don't know if there is a way to fire off all get() calls at the same time, and then wait for all of them to complete. But might it be a solution to use [Tasks.whenAllComplete(Task...<?> tasks)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAllComplete(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E...))?

Comment: Yeah, that's what it would be in Java indeed. And I see now that Sergey answered with an approach like that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, users come one by one, not in parallel. To achieve the parallelism you can use a couple of features from [`kotlinx-coroutines-play-services`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services) library:

```
val tasks: MutableList<Deferred<DataSnapshot>> = mutableListOf()
for (i in 1..10) {
    val randomId = Random.nextInt(i)
    val deferredTask = usersRef.child(questionIdsList[randomId]).get().asDeferred()
    tasks.add(deferredTask)
}

tasks.awaitAll().forEach { dataSnapshot ->
    val randomUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
    if (!userList.contains(randomUser)) {
        userList.add(randomUser)
    }
}
```

Using [`asDeferred`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/as-deferred.html) extension function we can convert a `Task` into a `Deferred`.

And then using [`awaitAll()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/await-all.html) extension function on `Collection<Deferred<T>>` we will wait while all users are loaded in parallel.

Comment: Let me try that and get back. Thanks.

Comment: but I guess the condition in `while` statement should be changed. Changing it on `for` loop...