# Firebase Realtime Database wait until the data is retrieved

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I have a map containing the keys of my Firebase Realtime Database and want to retrieve the corresponding key data and put it in the result data list. How can I execute the loop sequentially? Basically, block the Firebase listener until it gets the result and only then iterate to the next key in the loop.

```
fun functionA() {

     val resultFileDataList = List<DataSnapshot>()
     for ((key, value) in filesMap) {
           val dbRef = database.child("files").child(key)
           dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                 override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
                 override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        resultFileDataList.add(dataSnapshot)
                      }
                })
      }

    callFunctionB() // call this function only after all the data in the loop above is retrieved
}
```

I tried `runBlocking {}` but no luck.

Comment: Do you know exactly how many elements should exist in the list when all files are added? is it a fixed number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using this way by utilizing the Task. [Tasks.whenall()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#whenAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)) will wait until all task are done.

```
fun functionA() {

    val taskList = mutableListOf<Task<DataSnapshot>>()
    val resultFileDataList = List<DataSnapshot>()

    for ((key, value) in filesMap) {
        val databaseReferenceTask: Task<DataSnapshot> = database.child("files").child(key).get()
        taskList.add(databaseReferenceTask)

        val resultTask = Tasks.whenAll(taskList)
        resultTask.addOnCompleteListener {
            for (task in taskList) {
                val snapshotKey: String? = task.result.key
                val snapShotValue = task.result
            }
            
            callFunctionB() 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Kotlin, then the simplest solution would be to use [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html). In this way, you can use suspend functions and call await for each read operation. To achieve that, please check the following article:

- [How to read data from Firebase Realtime Database using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5)

If you need however to [pipeline the requests over its existing connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786), then you should consider using [kotlinx-coroutines-play-services](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services), case in which you can use [awaitAll()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/await-all.html) function.

Comment: I am exactly looking for pipelining requests but the example link you shared is for iOS. Could you share similar code for android? I tried searching for it but couldn't find anything for android.

Comment: I found a useful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70436260/how-to-optimize-real-time-database-calls-when-getting-10-random-users). Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
suspend fun functionA() = suspendCoroutine<List<DataSnapshot>>{ continuation ->

    val resultFileDataList = mutableListOf<DataSnapshot>()
    for ((key, value) in filesMap) {
        val dbRef = database.child("files").child(key)
        dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                resultFileDataList.add(dataSnapshot)
                if(resultFileDataList.size == fileMaps.size){
                    continuation.resume(resultFileDataList)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And then you can call the functions wherever you want like so:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    val dataSnapshotList = functionA()
    functionB(dataSnapshotList)
}
```

Bear in mind that it is better to use the following to bind the coroutine to the lifecycle of the activity:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val dataSnapshotList = functionA()
    functionB(dataSnapshotList)
}
```

### Note:

This will basically wait for all the data to change so that the `onDataChanged()` is triggered and when the last file is added, continues with the coroutine and returns the value. Depending on your user's behaviour, this could take a long time to complete since even if one of the files is not changed, the coroutine will not resume.

Also, if `onCancelled()` is triggered for one file, this will never complete. So if you are absolutely sure that `onDataChanged()` will be triggered for all files, use this. Otherwise, implement some sort of timeout functionality to resume with the incomplete data.

Comment: Thanks for adding this. I do not want to depend on the size of list and that is not fixed and can be changed in between as well. I am looking for similar code in android that awaits for all responses. [Pipelining requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786)