# How can i wait for loop until firebase call finish in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

```
var resultList = listOf<FriendListRow>()

val asyncTask = async {
    for (i in friendListRowList) {
        databaseFirebase
            .getReference("Profiles")
            .child(i.userUUID)
            .child("profile")
            .child("userProfilePictureUrl")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                val friendListRow = FriendListRow(i.userEmail,i.userUUID,i.registerUUID,it.value as String,i.lastMessage)
                resultList += friendListRow
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                this@callbackFlow.trySendBlocking(Error(it.localizedMessage))
            }
    }
}

asyncTask.invokeOnCompletion {
    this@callbackFlow.trySendBlocking(Success(resultList))
}
```

i want to get resultList from firebasedatabase call but resultlist return empty. It seems for loop dooesn't wait until succeess listener ends or invokOnCompletion doesnt wait or another something happen, i dont know. How can i solve that.

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, a more convenient way would be to use [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html). To achieve that, you can read the following article, [How to read data from Firebase Realtime Database using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5).

Comment: Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70437944/1731626. The main idea is to fill `val tasks: MutableList<Deferred<DataSnapshot>>` in the loop and use `tasks.awaitAll()` to wait until all tasks are done.